# How to read value from a text file in ruby using watir based on position

Tags: html, ruby, text, watir

Can some one please help me write a code in Ruby using Watir so that I can read any value from a given text file based on position and use it as parameter for any field in a web application.

I am new to Ruby and have no idea how to implement this solution.

What I need is, for example, lets say there is a text file called "Test.txt" in d drive main folder. Say it has text like this

13085216660000019999

In the above text I want read the value from position 4 to 8 and i.e '8521' and store it as variable and use it in a text field as given below

ie.textField(:name, "de2").set 'Variable got from reading the file'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ? The [3..6] indicate the 4th position (starting from 0) until the 8th

```
def my_method var
  puts var
end

File.read("read_var_from_file.txt").each_line{ |line|my_method line[3..6] }
```

When file contents is

```
13085216660000019999
13085226660000019999
13085236660000019999
```

gives as output

```
8521
8522
8523
```

EDIT: based on the comment here another version which let you change the begin and end position by line

```
def read_var file, line_nr, vbegin, vend
    IO.readlines(file)[line_nr][vbegin..vend]
end

puts read_var("read_var_from_file.txt", 0, 1, 3) #line 0, beginning at 1, ending at 3
#=>308

puts read_var("read_var_from_file.txt", 1, 3, 6)

#=>8522
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to read each line for a different positions... Like in first line I want to read position 4 to 8 and in second line I want to read from position 1 to 3

Comment: Also I tried this solution but it is getting the entire line and not the postion which we have mentioned...

Comment: sure, have added it to my answer

Comment: Hi Peter, Similarly can you also please suggest how to write into a file instaed of reading.. as I implemented this solution , I am running into a scenario where I even have to write into a file... Is there a way to implement the same solution to even write to a file for require position for require line....

Comment: yes, the easiest way would be to read in the file, replace the variable at some lines and write it back with a File.write. Try it and if you get stuck publish your code in a new question and leave me a message here, i'll see then what i can do

Comment: Hi Peter, I tires couple of solution and could not get it to work. I have added a new post with all the details. Would be helpful if you could take a look and suggest me a solution... Thanks in advance 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382956/how-to-write-some-value-to-a-text-file-in-ruby-based-on-position

Comment: @anagraj, made you a sample ther that works with a replacement

Comment: I checked again and it works good. it is problem with the note pad that it is printing in single line. When i check in edit plus tool it is showing up correct... Thanks again